# IDE that allows SVN operations on remote server

Tags: ssh, svn, ide

Is there any Windows GUI, preferably an IDE, that allows one to connect to a server via SSH, modify (html, in this case) files and then commit them to SVN?

I've been fiddling with Netbeans and Aptana and I can't find a way to do it there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of things, I actually ended up going with [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), which is free and works on Mac OS X and Linux as well as Windows.

It doesn't quite support what I wanted out of the box, but I made it happen with a dirty little macro. So far it is working fine for my needs. Not the most elegant solution but it's good enough!

Here is the source for the macro: https://gist.github.com/2035258

Answer (score 1):

While I've never needed to use svn and don't know the intricacies of what happens locally or in the server, it is my understanding that the various svn plugins for [Visual studio](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us) would do what you want.

A list can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453481/what-subversion-plugins-for-visual-studio-are-there), in addition there seems to exist a [Tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/) [plugin](https://tsvnaddin.codeplex.com/) for VS as well.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Designer](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/downloads.php) Supports SVN & GIT, it's a pretty decent IDE too!